# Asynchronous async / await

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have these code lines:

```
MongoClient.connect(customer_db_url)
    .then(async (customerDB) => {
        const callDB = await MongoClient.connect(call_db_url);
        return await customerDB.listCollections({ name: { $regex: /contact_/ } })
            .forEach(async (collection) => {
                await console.log(collection.name);
            });
    })
    .then(() => console.log('Done!'))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
```

The console logs `Done!` before any `collection.name` inside. I haven't got this. I thought `async` `await` keywords would make sure the asynchronous functions to be fulfilled before executing the next ones. Even if I don't return there but after all `forEach`, the result is still the same.

Comment: `console.log()` isn't an async function!

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return a promise, if it's the `Array.prototype` method. Or is it some other method?